# How to create single array of id's from parent and child array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, codeigniter

I'm Trying to create single array that contains all the ID of parent and child from the database.
But all I was getting is single data.

My ideal output is:

```
array('160', '161', '162', '163', '164');
```

what am I getting is only

```
array('160');
```

Here is what I've done so far.

```
public function arrayId(array $elements) {
    $where_in = array();
    foreach($elements as $element){
        if($element->isArray) {
            $elems = $this->my_model->select_where('tbl_policies', array('parent_id' => $element->id));
            $this->arrayId($elems);
        }
        $where_in[] = $element->id;
   }
   return $where_in;
}
$id = 160; //for instance
$elements = $this->my_model->select_where('tbl_policies', array('id' => $id));
$where_in = $this->arrayId($elements);
                    
die(print_r($where_in));
```

and the data I'm fetching here:
**tbl_policies**
[image]

It's kinda difficult for me to construct questions. So please if something is not clear, do comment below, I'll try my best to make it more understandable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `$elements` contain here to begin with, which ID did you actually use in that where condition?

Comment: @CBroe you can see after the public function.

Comment: No, I can _not_ see what _value_ `$id` actually contains, by just looking at `$id`. And please use proper indentation in the code you are posting here.

Comment: You call `$this->arrayId($elems);` inside your loop, but then you are not doing any thing with its return value.

Comment: Looks like you have code laying around in a class but not in a method? Maybe if you clear up the code so its more REAL it may help

Comment: Your goal is to delete a parent record in the database with all its children and grandchildren. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand, that you want to delete a parent with all its children and grandchildren. But you do it not directly and sequentially rather want to collect all ids of the records to be deleted. You should go following steps:

1. Parent-Id (example 160) is already known. Add this to your list.
2. Write a recursive function such as getChildrenIds(parentId).
3. Within this function you should iterate over children. And if a child has the flag "isArray" (according to your application logic) then you should call getChildrenIds(currentChildId)

I have written following function. It should work.

```
    public function getChildrenIds( int $parentId, array &$idList) {

    $idList[] = $parentId;
    $records = $this->my_model->select_where('tbl_policies', array('parent_id' => $parentId));
    foreach($records as $r){
        if($r->isArray)
            $this->getChildrenIds($r->id, $idList);
        else
            $idList[] = $r->id;
    }
    return;
}

public function CollectIds(){   
    $id = 160; //for instance
    $where_in = array();     
    $this->getChildrenIds($id, $where_in);
}
```

Please notice, that $where_in passed by reference to the recursive function getChildrenIds() and filled there.